# mysql inner join 3 tables and union

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm used to make queries with sparql, but i have to do this one with mysql that i don't really know the syntax.
I have these three tables:

Products:

```
    id o
    1 p1
    2 p2
```

Specification:

```
    id o
    3 sp1
    4 sp2
```

Source:

```
    id o
    1 s1
    3 s1
    2 s2
    4 s2
```

As we see, the products and the specifications can be connected with the source different ids, so i guess i have to make 2 selects with 2 inner joins between source > product and source > specification and an inner join between the 2 selects :

```
      SELECT * FROM
        (
            SELECT pt.o as po, st.id as psID, st.o as pso 
            FROM source_test st
            inner join products_test pt on st.id = pt.id
        ) x INNER JOIN  
        (
            SELECT st2.o as spo, st1.id as spsID,st1.o as spso      
            FROM source_test st1
            inner join specification_test st2 on st1.id =st2.id
        ) y
```

This gives:

```
    po  psID    pso spo spsID   spso
    p1  1   s1  sp1 3   s1
    p2  2   s2  sp1 3   s1
    p1  1   s1  sp2 4   s2
    p2  2   s2  sp2 4   s2
```

Now i need to filter product (po) and the specification (spo) that have the same source (pso),(spso)

I'm i on doing things the right way, what could be the continuation or a good query to get:

```
    po  spo spso
    p1  sp1 s1
    p2  sp1 s2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you remove the SQL Server tag.  It's a different product.  Many SQL Server solutions will not work in MySQL, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing i had to do is to to filter y ON x.pso = y.spso

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT product.o as po, source.s as psID, source.o as pso FROM source
        inner join product
            on source.s = product.s
    ) x INNER JOIN  
    (
        SELECT specification.o as spo, source.s as spsID, source.o as spso FROM source
        inner join specification
            on source.s = specification.s
    ) y ON x.pso = y.spso
```

result:

```
    po  psID    pso spo spsID   spso
    p1  1   s1  sp1 3   s1
    p2  2   s2  sp2 4   s2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.o, s.o, so.o
from products p
    left join specification s
    left join source so on p.id=s.id and p.id = so.id;
```

Comment: No `ON` clause for the first `LEFT JOIN`? Is that valid MySQL syntax? (Syntax error according to most other products, and ANSI SQL too.)

Comment: Also where is the condition pso <> spso ?

Comment: @jarlh I can confirm that this is valid mysql syntax

Answer (score 0):

Add `ON x.pso = y.spso` to your query:

```
SELECT x.po, y.spo, y.spso
FROM
(
    SELECT products_test.o as po, source_test.id as psID, source_test.o as pso FROM source_test
     inner join products_test
        on source_test.id = products_test.id
) x INNER JOIN  
(
   SELECT specification_test.o as spo, source_test.id as spsID,source_test.o as spso      
    FROM source_test
     inner join specification_test on source_test.id =specification_test.id
) y     
  ON x.pso = y.spso
```

Comment: Actually, this is the answer that i gave.

Comment: It looks like we answered at the same time. 
Cheers!